# importar datos de csv y/o txt delimitados a una tabla en access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

tengo un proyecto en el que mi interfaz de usuario esta en excel y mi base de datos esta en access.

debo crear un formulario para que cualquier usuario pueda buscar y seleccionar un archivo (csv o txt) "Esta parte ya la tengo" luego de esto debo enviar los datos del archivo seleccionado a una tabla (que un no existe) en access.

he intentado utilizar el metodo DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim sin exito, ya que si importa el archivo y crea una nueva tabla pero no lo delimita, lo deja todo en un solo campo.

Alguien puede indicarme como usar el metodo de manera correcta para lograr lo que requiero.

A continuación mi código:
Sub pruebas()

```
 strBase = path & NombreBase

 Dim appAccess As Access.Application

 Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

 appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strBase & ".accdb", False
 DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , tableName:="import_table3", Filename:=" Ruta y nombre archivo", hasfieldnames:=True
 Set appAccess = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Navegando en la web encontré que para que funcione correctamente debo primero en la base de datos crear una muestra de la importación, esto con el fin de definir los parámetros del tipo de carácter ("," o ";" o "|" o " ") entre otros, y después llamar dentro del método esa "Plantilla" guardada. Lo anterior no me sirve por que perdería todo el sentido de automatización.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Prueba mejor a importar el archivo a Access como archivo Excel, no como texto. Mira [Método DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet (Access)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet)

Comment: Hola, Después de investigar mucho debí desarrollar una previa, me explico importar el archivo txt,csv  a mi libro de excel y desde allí hacer Método DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet (Access)

Answer (score 0):

te falta por rellenar el 2do parámetro de `TransferText:<SpecificationName> DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, ????????? , tableName:="import_table3", Filename:=" Ruta y nombre archivo", hasfieldnames:=True`
La forma mas fácil es que hagas la importación de manera manual usando el asistente de importación, y guardando la especificación (donde dices cual es el `caracter` de separación, si añade columna id o no, etc...) con el nombre que elijas.

Luego este nombre lo usas como 2do parámetro y así `Access` sabe como debe importar el archivo